# Well explained algorithms for indexing and searching in metric spaces

Tags: database, algorithm, postgresql, data-mining

I need to implement some kind of metric space search in Postgres(*) (PL or PL/Python). So, I'm looking for good sources (or papers) with a very clear and crisp explanation of the machinery behind these ideas, in such way that I can implement it myself.

I would prefer clarity over efficiency.

(*) The need for that is described better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122990/how-to-determine-if-a-record-in-every-source-represents-the-same-person).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially for geographical data, look at [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) first to see if you need to implement anything. If you do, start with the papers listed in the [Wikipedia entry on GiST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST).

Looking at your link, it seems your metric space is strings with some sort of edit distance as the metric. A nice but oldish overview of some solutions is given by [Navarro, Baeza-Yates, Sutinen, and Tarhio, IEEE Data Engineering Bulletin, 2001](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.5629); the related papers on Citeseer could also be useful. [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/) is a newer technique that might be useful, but a lot of the papers are heavy on math.

Answer (score 1):

[BK-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) are useful for indexing and searching anything that obeys the triangle inequality, metric spaces included. The canonical example is searching for strings within a given edit distance of a target. I wrote an article about that [here](http://blog.notdot.net/archives/30-Damn-Cool-Algorithms,-Part-1-BK-Trees.html).

Unfortunately, there's no built in support for this in Postgres. You could implement it yourself using [GIST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/gist-intro.html), but obviously that'll be a lot of work. I can't think of any way to implement it without writing your own indexes short of storing the tree in a table, which obviously isn't going to be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://sisap.org where many modern metric indexes are listed, including BK-trees. You can find code in C to try different alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Some techniques that involve space search that might help you are Hill-Climbing, Neural Network Training, Genetic Algorithm, and Particle Swarm.

You will also need to define a distance metric over your metric space. Have you done so?(& out of curiosity, what is it, if you have done so)